# Instance variable is not shared among methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Why instance variable is not working in Ruby on rails?

Here is my code:

```
class books
  @price = true
  def new
    p(@price)
  end
end
```

In console it prints `nil` why? I want it to be printed true.

Comment: Be careful with defining methods with important-looking names like `new`. You might break your ruby (this particular case is fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In console it prints `nil` why? I want it to be printed true.

That instance variable assignment is on another object, the class itself. Naturally, an object (instance of a class) can't see instance variables of another object (the class). Instead, you can set it on the instance level

```
class Books
  def initialize
    @price = true
  end

  def hello
    p @price
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to define instance variable on the class level. Consider using `@@price = true` or `cattr_accessor(:price) { true }` from Active Support.